# extract html text from inside of the tag

Tags: php, regex

i need help to extract all the text inside each tag of the following html using regex or any other method each on separate line .  i am using PHP .

```
<p><strong>Ingredientes (para 700gr aprox)</strong></p>
<p>Se necesitará papel de aluminio para envolver</p>
<p><strong>Secos</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>2 1/4 taza de harina de gluten</li>
<li>1/2 taza de levadura nutricional</li>
<li>1 taza de pan molido</li>

<li>2 1/2 cdtas de sal</li>
<li>1 cdta de comino</li>
<li>1/2 cdta de pimienta negra molida</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Líquidos</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>2 1/4 tazas de agua fría</li>
<li>2 cdas de caldo de verduras</li>
<li>2 cdas de aceite de oliva</li>
<li>2 cdas de sillao o salsa de soja</li>

<li>2 cdtas de ajo molido</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Preparación</strong></p>
```

if i put all lines of above html in a single line what will be the change in regex/other method ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on the string.

Example:

```
$text = "<p>Some <strong>text.</strong></p>";
$strippedText = strip_tags($text);
echo($strippedText);
```

**Output:**

> Some text.